# Merging an array but keeping values that weren't in the other array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, ini

What I'm trying to do is read an INI file with PHP and then merge the array with another array. For example:

```
$a1 = parse_ini_file("file1.ini",true);
$a2 = parse_ini_file("file2.ini",true);
$info = array_merge($a1,$a2);
```

Now here's my problem, if I merge the arrays: The sub-arrays will be completely replaced if it is written in the second ini file.

**file1.ini**

```
[BASIC]
title=Title
otherInfo=1
[SECONDSECTION]
thestuffs=3
```

**file2.ini**

```
[BASIC]
otherInfo=6
```

---

Now if I were to look at the merged data `$info` I would get something like this:

```
$info = array(
    "BASIC" => array(
        "otherInfo" => 6
    ),
    "SECONDSECTION" => array(
        "thestuffs" => 3
    ),
);
```

**DESIRED RESULT:**

```
$info = array(
    "BASIC" => array(
        "title" => "Title"
        "otherInfo" => 6
    ),
    "SECONDSECTION" => array(
        "thestuffs" => 3
    ),
);
```

Comment: You have to use `array_merge_recursive` instead of `array_merge`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `array_merge()` to [`array_merge_recursive()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

Comment: Not exactly what i'm looking for, but I think I can make it work fairly fine with a little extra checking. And checking is never bad.